# How to input a string or integer to a C++ program from the command line?

Tags: c++

Id like to read input from the command line and if it is an integer, write it together with its hex format to a file and if the user enters "end", the loop should terminate.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

void numToFile() {
    int i;
    std::string input;
    
    std::ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open("outputFile.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);

    while (input != "end") {
        std::cin >> input;
        ofs << input << " = 0x" << std::ios::hex << input << std::endl;
    }
    ofs.close();
}

int main() {
    numToFile();
}
```

However, in the output file, I find this output:

```
12 = 0x204812
34 = 0x204834
49 = 0x204849
end = 0x2048end
```

Not quite sure as to how direct the input to string or to an integer to convert to the Hex format.

---

Edit:

```
Including `stoi`:

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>


void numToFile() {
    int i;
    std::string input;
    
    std::ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open("outputFile.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);

    while (input != "end") {
        std::cin >> input;
        ofs << std::setw(5) << std::setfill('0');

        //                         NOT: std::ios::hex !?
        ofs << input << " = 0x" << std::hex               << std::stoi(input) << std::endl;
    }

    ofs.close();
}
```

Comment: Your `input` variable is a `std::string` - if you want to convert that to an `int` you have to do it explicitly, e.g.: via `std::stoi`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Comment: The `hex` in `cout << hex` is not `std::ios::hex` (a bitflag which has the value 2048), it is [`std::hex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex), a special object called an "I/O manipulator" which changes the options on the stream it is inserted into instead of generating output.  Well, "I/O manipulator" can be a function object or a plain function and this one is actually a plain function.

Comment: I included the `stoi` call. The conversion is written to the output file but on entering `end`, the program crashes:
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFD47663B29 in HexTableToFile.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::invalid_argument at memory location 0x000000EBDCEFF740. occurred

Comment: You do the input != "end" check *after* you try to convert it to an int. You need to fix this too.

Comment: The command line arguments are passed to your `int main(int argc, char**argv)`

Comment: @Cem What do you mean? `input` is the condition for the while loop. Conversion to int happens inside of the while. Do I need to convert it back (to int?) before the loop closes?

Comment: When this program reaches the last word of input file (end), `std::cin >> input` puts "end" into `input`, and then `std::stoi` tries to convert this "end" text to hex. This is also a mistake. You should change the code to check for input == "end" after reading the input and before using it. You may be getting std::invalid_argument because you give "end" to `std::stoi`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether input is valid or not as soon as possible .

```
    void numToFile() {
    int i;
    std::string input;
    
    std::ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open("outputFile.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);

    while (std::cin>>input) {
        if(input == "end") break;
        ofs << std::setw(5) << std::setfill('0');

        //                         NOT: std::ios::hex !?
        ofs << input << " = 0x" << std::hex               << std::stoi(input) << std::endl;
    }

    ofs.close();
}
```